# MPMoviePlayerController background color won't stick

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to change the background color of my MPMoviePlayerController, and I can't get it to stick.

I'm using:

```
moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I can see the background flash red while the video is loading. As soon as it is loaded, the background goes black again. I've tried setting the color after playback has started, but that has no effect.

I'm using iOS 5.

Edit: I'm actually attempting to set the background to [UIColor clearColor], not red. I should have asked my question properly in the first place.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't work with clear color seems to indicate that there is either a subview that the answers below aren't accounting for, or there's some custom drawing going on. Any particular reason why you'd like it to be something other than black?

Comment: Are you trying to get a clear background to show behind the movie? Not sure if the decode hardware supports transparency…

Comment: No, just the border around the movie (on the sides with 4:3 movie, top/bottom with 16:9). It is black by default, when using the redColor, it shows a red border properly. The movie player is sitting on a background image, and the client really wants that image to be visible, rather than just black.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`backgroundColor` on `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated and `view` is documented as read-only.  See: [Deprecated MPMoviePlayerController Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/backgroundColor)

> **backgroundColor** 
>  The color of the background area behind the movie. (Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 3.1. Get the view from the
>   **backgroundView** property and set its color directly.)
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *backgroundColor

So I would try using:

```
moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: This works great, and I had tried it once before, but my original goal was to use [UIColor clearColor]. When that didn't work, I started messing around with red to make things more obvious. Unfortunately, clearColor doesn't work with the code you posted. Thoughts?

Comment: @EricReid did you also try to set `moviePlayer.backgroundView.opaque = NO`?