# MPMoviePlayerController existed black background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I make iOS app.

I use MPMoviePlayerController, but this shows black background.

I think this problem can solve by this URL, but I can't understand use way.
[MPMoviePlayerController background color won't stick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974349/mpmovieplayercontroller-background-color-wont-stick)

My code is this.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie_files" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                initWithContentURL:videoURL];

//setting
moviePlayer.scalingMode =MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 200)];    

//notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

//clearColor
UIView *subV =[[UIView alloc]init];
for(subV in moviePlayer.backgroundView.subviews) {
    subV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
[moviePlayer.view addSubview:subV];    
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
//show white screen
```

Please tell the clear background way.

Comment: What happens when you use `[UIColor redColor]`, does it change the color? I don't think `clearColor` works in such a case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
for(UIView *aSubView in moviePlayer.view.subviews) {
    aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Was trying to fix this one for a while, thanks!! you are the man :D

Answer (score 10):

Setting Background view's color alone didn't work for me.

I think the view background color should also be changed. I added one more line of code and now it woks fine. The entire video background is transparent now. :)  Thanks @Jordi

```
moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

for(UIView *aSubView in moviePlayer.view.subviews) {
    aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: line "moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];"
is redundant: backgroundView is a subview of moviewPlayer.view, so the color is changed while you iterate over subviews in your "for" cycle. Thanks.

Comment: @Scarmysun well, I had to include it.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to hide the video player and then show it when it is ready to display

caveat needs IO6>= i believe:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459855/401896